# carousel icon is not showing in correct format?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

carousel is not working properly. I am able to slide the image but icon for carousel is not showing correctly. Please see the image. My bootstrap version is `bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js`

```
 <div >
     <carousel interval=5000>
        <slide ng-repeat="photo in photos track by $index" active="slide.active">
          <picture class="lateral-picture" ng-if=photo>
               <img ng-src="{{url}}" style='max-width : 100%; max-height : 100%'>
          </picture>
       </slide>
     </carousel>
 </div>
```

In console I am getting message 
`carousel is now deprecated. Use uib-carousel instead.
http://localhost:3000/home/static/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Here you can see carousel icon but it is wrap.  Why it is showing like that....

[image]

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: are you using bootstrap carousel?

Comment: It appears to be a missing font, which might be used to display as 'sliding arrows'.

Comment: @Goldenowner, yes this not loading` glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Did you made a customized file in bootstrap to get your Glyphicons?

Comment: You can see [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) you should be using `uib-carousel`. Also you are pathing wrong to your glyphicons, you probably bound {{url}} wrong.

Answer (score 0):

404 error might be because of 2 issues

1. Make sure path you are referring to glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff file is correct.
2. Make sure you have added .woff file type in MIME Extension. If you are using IIS then follow the steps mentioned here http://projectseven.com/tutorials/servers/iis-woff/index.htm